# Windows to embedded port: data and code memory size

Tags: memory, embedded, size, porting

I am in the process of porting a windows 7 library to an embedded platform. In order to do so my employer asks me the amount of memory (and CPU but let us concentrate on the memory for now) that my system will need once ported - so he can size the board to my needs.

I had a look on the internet and there seem not be exist much information about this question, hence my questions:

1. in order to get a rough idea of the memory footprint of the code in flash memory (code only without memory for data), I read on the Internet that I should sum the size of all the dlls I use. It seems that all compilers and platforms give a different size for the code footprint but overall the size of the code (without data) is often very close. Do you confirm?
2. in order to deal with the memory required by the data only (heap + stack but no code), I had a look at the task manager (and process explorer). It seems the overall amount of data which I use is specified in the 'peak working set'. I have a few questions about it though:

2.a. Does the 'working set' include the heap + stack memory or does it correspond to the heap only?

2.b. Does the 'working set' include the size for the code as well? (as I am on windows 7, the code is also stored in RAM and not in flash as on embedded systems), or does it only correspond to the data?

2.c. it seems the 'peak working set' reflects the maximum amount of physical memory that was actually in RAM from the time the program was started, but it does not reflect the size the program could take afterwards (if I happen to allocate memory at runtime - which would be bad ;) - the peak value would go on increasing). Do you confirm?

2.d. Hence, do you also confirm that if I do not allocate memory at runtime, the 'peak working set' should roughly be the maximum size of RAM my embedded system will need? Up to a bit of size difference due to the difference in systems technology...

Thanks,

Antoine.

Comment: Best thing'd be a debugger that tracks malloc() and whatnot, and you fuzz the system to exercise it to the fullest. What you see in task manager is not particularly exact.

Comment: The OS optimizes memory usage by utilizing virtual memory and giving processes as much physical memory as is reasonable. Working set numbers are telling you how much physical memory was given to the process to run. That can be much less than the process needs, less than its code + data + heap + stack size. You can't rely on the working set numbers when porting to a different OS and hardware. It makes little sense to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are intending to run your application on Windows Embedded, then looking at the code and data usage in Windows is not going to be much of an indicator of anything useful!

1) DLLs are libraries - not all the code within them will be utilised by your code.  Most embedded systems are statically linked and the linker will link only modules that are actually referenced in your by your code.  So taking the sum of the DLL dependencies is likley to lead to a gross over estimation of memory requirement.

2) Windows memory management is profligate with memory use - because it can be and to do so generally improves performance of typical desktop systems.  For example, an thread stack in Windows is typically of the order to 2Mb - you may seldom use that much, but Windows gives it to you in any case because it can and to do so errs on the side of safety.  A thread stack in an embedded system will typically range from a few tens of bytes to a few tens of kilobytes - it depends on your application.

Windows task manager shows what Windows allocates to your process, that may not relate to what your process needs.  Also your application is using Windows services - all the memory used for kernel and device services will not show up as part of your process, but your embedded system may still need those.

If you do use your Windows prototype code to assess the embedded system requirements, then your best place to start is by getting the linker to generate a map file, which will give a detailed description of memory usage in terms of statically allocated data and code size.

Code size depends not only on the performance of the compiler, but also on the efficiency of the instruction set.  Some architectures achieve higher code density than others.  Windows application code size is never a good indicator of embedded code size because its execution environment is likley to be so much different.  For example an pre-emptive multitasking RTOS kernel on a 32bit ARM can be implemented in less than 10Kb of code, a file system perhaps another 10, and network stack anything from 10 to 30K, USB another 10.  As you can see this is a different world to desktop code.

Data memory usage is more easily determined perhaps; but you do that through analysis of your application rather than observing what Windows does.  There is the data your application instantiates directly, and then there is data instantiated by libraries and device drivers you might call - in Windows the latter is likley to be relatively large and out of your control.  Typical embedded systems libraries for things such a s network stacks, USB, file systems etc. are fall smaller and far more deterministic in both performance and size.

Your better bet is to describe your application in terms of its general purpose, performance requirements, real-time constraints, and its hardware requirements (display, networking, I/O, mass storage etc.), and then look at comparable solutions or at the libraries you will need to implement your solution; most embedded systems are "bare board" and do not have the services you find in Windows unless you write them or use third-party solutions - Windows is seldom a comparable solution to an embedded system.

---

If it is just a library rather than an application, then build it for a likley target using a Windows hosted GCC cross-compiler and see how big it ends up.  You don't need hardware for that or even expend any money.

Comment: Hum... I think I am getting the main point here: the comparison between both systems is not straightforward and it is rather risky. It seems embedded systems are really much different. One question though, is the size of the stack determined by the system then? Is there a way to know about it?

Comment: @user1524055 The maximum size of the stack can be limited not only by the amount of RAM but also by the CPU (if it's an unusual CPU). The size that you'll need is determined by your code, by how much stuff it has as local variables, by the depth of function calls (especially, recursive ones). If ISRs are going to use the current stack, you'll need to account for their stack usage as well.

Comment: @user1524055: Most windows compilers apply a (large) default stack size per thread, but allow the developer to allocate a different size. In most embedded environments using no OS or a simple RTOS, the developer must analyse and apply stack size for each thread, and in some architectures also the interrupt stack.  You control *everything*. If you have never dome embedded development, I strongly suggest that you get an expert.